# What is "Read Access Violation... was nullptr"?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, nullptr

I could use some help. I have been trying to get my deletion function to work correctly, but no matter what I seem to do it always gives me a "was nullptr" error. My code is a bit messy since I've been panicking and frantically trying anything that comes to mind. I am ready to start over if I need to though. Everywhere I have looked for information about nullptr has not really given an explanation that I actually understand. My understanding is that a "was nullptr" error is given when you try to dereference a pointer/node, but I could never find a way to handle the issue that made sense to me. Any help is really appreciated. My code is:

```
 `

BT::BT()
{
    node* root = NULL;
}

char BT::FindReplacement(node* parent, char param)
{
    if (parent == NULL) //In case someone tries to delete a node while there aren't any nodes in the Tree
    {
        return NULL;
    } 

    parent = parent->right;
    while (parent->left != NULL)
    {
        parent = parent->left;
    }

    return parent->data;
}

void BT::leafDriver()
{
    int count = 0;
    leafCount(root, count); 
}

void BT::leafCount(node* start, int count)
{


    if ((start->left == NULL) && (start->right == NULL))
    {
        count++;
    }

    if (start->left != NULL)
    {
        leafCount(start->left, count);
    }

    if(start->right != NULL)
    {
        leafCount(start->right, count);
    }
cout << " There are " << count << " number of leaves in the BST" << endl;

}


void BT::deletionDriver(char param)
{
    deletion(root, param);
}

void BT::deletion(node* parent, char param)
{

    if (parent->data < param) 
    {
        parent->left = parent->left->left;
        deletion(parent -> left, param);
        cout << "checking left node" << endl;
    }

    else if (parent->data > param)
    {
        parent->right = parent->right->right;
        deletion(parent->right, param);
        cout << "checking right node" << endl;
    }

    else if (parent->data == param)
    {
        //Case 1: No Children
        if (parent->left == NULL && parent->right == NULL)
        {
            delete parent;
            parent = NULL;

        }


        //Case 2: One Child
        else if ((parent->right == NULL) && (parent->left != NULL))
        {
            node* temp = parent;
            parent = parent->left;
            delete temp;
        }

        else if (parent->left == NULL)
        {
            node* temp = parent;
            parent - parent->right;
            delete temp;
        }

        //Case 3: Two Children
        else if ((parent->left != NULL) && (parent->right != NULL))
        {
            char tempParam;
            tempParam = FindReplacement(parent, param);
            parent->data = tempParam;
            deletion(parent->right, tempParam);
        }
    }

    else 
        cout << "Item is not found in BST" << endl;
}`
```

Comment: The code repeatedly does stuff like "parent->left = parent->left->left;", without checking if "parent->left" is NULL. This is the likely cause of your crashes.

Comment: You should really put your program in a debugger and verify where the issue is and guard against it.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have code like this:

```
parent = parent->right;
```

you need to check that the value you have newly assigned to parent is not null. In other words your code should always look something like this:

```
parent = parent->right;
if ( parent == nullptr ) {
    // handle null case
}
else {
    // handle case when there is another node
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (parent->left != NULL)
```

changed it to

```
while (parent != NULL)
```

and it should work